# differences CrawlerProcess and scrapy crawl somespider in commandline in scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

case 1 : `scrapy crawl somespider` type several times (same time, using nohup background)

case 2 : using CrawlerProcess and configure multispider in python script and run

what is diffrences cases? i already tried case2 using 5 spiders but not so fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scrapy crawl` uses one process for each spider, while `CrawlerProcess` uses a single Twisted Reactor on one process (while also doing some things under the hood which I'm not so sure) to run multiple spiders at once.

So, basically:

1. `scrapy crawl` -> more than one process
2. `CrawlerProcess` -> runs only one process with a Twisted Reactor